# Is there a R function or package to calculate the p value of a slope in a GLMM with interactions

Tags: r, regression, mixed-models, p-value

Consider I have a linear mixed model with two continuous variables and use contrast coding for two factors with each two categories respectively (A,B). A random effect is optional.

```
contrasts(data$fac1) <- c(-.5,.5)
contrasts(data$fac2) <- c(-.5,.5)

model<-lme(Y~x1+x2+x1:fac1+x2:fac1+x1:fac2+x2:fac2+fac1+fac2+fac1:fac2, random=~1|group,data)
```

then the output will give me the main effects for x1 and x2 and the difference between slopes for fac1 and fac2.

But how can I calculate individual p-values for say the slope of x1 fac1=="A" and fac2=="B" ?

Is there an R package or do I have to calculate them manually ?

And if yes how? -following calls to `vcov()` adding up respective matrix entries and call to `pt()` (which df to use)?
Thanks!

Comment: I am curios about your formula, why specify each interaction with e.g. `x1 + fac1 + x1:fac1` when you can achieve the same with `x1*fac1`?

Comment: Also, I believe that `emmeans` is what you are looking for.

Comment: -you are right, it is just to illustrate all coefficients needed and because I do not want an interaction between x1 and x2, so I have not written say (x1+x2+fac1+fac2)^2.

Comment: thanks I will try emmeans, as this package is quite extensive do you may have an easy working example? -and do you know if I would need to correct for multiple testing in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You could try the `marginaleffects` package. (Disclaimer: I am the author.)

There are many vignettes on the website, including one with simple examples of mixed effects models with the `lme4` package: https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/marginaleffects/articles/lme4.html

You can specify the values of covariates using the `newdata` argument and the `datagrid` function. The covariates you do not specify in `datagrid` will be held at their means or modes:

```r
library(lme4)
library(marginaleffects)

mod <- glmer(am ~ mpg * hp + (1 | gear),
             data = mtcars,
             family = binomial)

marginaleffects(mod, newdata = datagrid(hp = c(100, 110), gear = 4))
#>   rowid     type term        dydx  std.error statistic   p.value
#> 1     1 response  mpg 0.077446700 0.33253683 0.2328966 0.8158417
#> 2     2 response  mpg 0.337725702 0.90506056 0.3731526 0.7090349
#> 3     1 response   hp 0.006199167 0.02647471 0.2341543 0.8148652
#> 4     2 response   hp 0.025604198 0.06770870 0.3781522 0.7053175
#>      conf.low  conf.high      mpg  hp gear
#> 1 -0.57431351 0.72920691 20.09062 100    4
#> 2 -1.43616041 2.11161181 20.09062 110    4
#> 3 -0.04569032 0.05808865 20.09062 100    4
#> 4 -0.10710242 0.15831082 20.09062 110    4
```

Comment: thanks, this is very helpful, but how would I combine the "hypothesis = .." for the problem above? -also the package does not support nlme, but I could switch to lme4.

Comment: @Jmmer there is a very detailed vignette on the `hypothesis` argument: https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/marginaleffects/articles/hypothesis.html

Comment: @Zheyuan Li I wrote a detailed comparison to some of the other packages out there. My (obviously very biased view) is that `emmeans` is more powerful in some areas, but that `marginaleffects` is more user-friendly and supports more models. `emmeans` used to be the only way to do complex contrasts and hyp tests, but `marginaleffects` can now do that as well. `margins` is very similar to `marginaleffects` but less powerful. Most other options are wrappers around `emmeans`. https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/marginaleffects/articles/alternative_software.html [edited the link]

Comment: thanks, I saw the vignette, but not sure how the problem above can be tackled according to this. May you add a minimal example according to the specified problem in our answer?

Comment: OK, I edited my answer. I don't think you want the `hypothesis` argument for that. You just want to specify values of the covariates at which to compute the slope. This is done in the `newdata` argument.

Comment: thanks! so running this on my model example would mean to do : marginaleffects(model, newdata = datagrid(fac1 = "A", fac2="B",x1=c(-1,1)) ? Unfortunately this ends up in an error message: 
Error: 
Unable to compute adjusted predictions for this model. Either the
`newdata` does not meet the requirements of the model's `predict()`
method, or this model is not supported. If you believe this model
should be supported, you can file a report on the Github Issue Tracker:
https://github.com/vincentarelbundock/marginaleffects/issues

Comment: You probably need to specify a value for the group variable, as I do with `gear` in my example. Or request a global mean using extra arguments as described in the vignette.

Comment: - I do this see comment above, but not working, unfortunately.

Comment: Is there a way to calculate this manually otherwise? via vcov?

Comment: maybe I can use bootstrapping from the lmeresampler package?

Comment: It's impossible to diagnose the problem without a minimal working example. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610